# Delete pack of commits that merged twice

Tags: git, merge

I had 2 branches, say `develop` and `feature`
I have local repo and same github repo.
There are no others commiters

It is approximately what I did: (I''m not sure in that all I say is correct_

I've merge `feature` to `develop`, then I've decided to reset it and re-merge it as `--no-ff`.
Then there was some trouble with no fast-forward `push` and I `pull` `origin/feature` to `feature`.
Then I tried to delete branch feature from `origin`(but not from my repo)
There are also was a rebase `master` in feature, but It was before first merge as far as I remember.

Now I have every commits of `feature` two times(green and black branches on picture):
[image]

It seems to be correct code now.

I want to delete on of this branches (On github and local repo). How can I achieve this?
Is it easy enough?

Answer (score 1):

You could rebase locally and force push it to wherever you need it. Figure out how many commits are in question, from the diagram it looks like 4. Check out the branch in question and do an interactive rebase.

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Remove the duplicate commits and verify that the final result matches what the original was by diffing two branches.

```
git diff develop..origin/develop
```

And then push to the remote

```
git push -f origin develop
```

Hope this works.